# Does there exist a surjective continuous map $D^2 \to S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

By considering the induced homomorphism on the fundamental groups, we know that there is no retract $D^2 \to S^1$. But is there *any* continuous surjection from $D^2$ to its boundary? It seems unlikely intuitively. How might we show this?

Idea: If there did, every loop $\gamma$ in $D^2$ would have to be such that $f \circ \gamma$ is contractible in $S^1$. So given a surjective map, perhaps we could find a "preimage loop" that must map to a nontrivial loop in $S^1$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The disc is a red herring here. You can write down a lot of surjective maps $D^2 \to S^1$; one might be $(r, \theta) \mapsto e^{2\pi i r}$.

This is not a fluke. Indeed, it's indicative of a much wider phenomenon. Let $X$ be a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Then $X$ is a continuous image of $[0,1]$ if and only if $X$ is compact, connected, and locally connected.

This is known as the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem; you can find a proof in Hans Sagan's book "Space-filling curves".

(As a note, this means that every compact, connected, locally connected subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ - in particular, every compact connected manifold - *is a quotient of $[0,1]$.*)

Comment: This is even true if you replace "subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$" with "metric space." Spaces that are the continuous image of an arc are often called Peano continua.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find a continuous map from a segment onto a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the disk to an interval and then map the interval to the circle via the usual quotient map.